# GCC Fail on Python2.7-alpine Docker Image

Tags: python, docker, gcc

I am trying to install `librabbitmq` and `MySQL-python` on `python:2.7-alpine` base image but getting gcc error. I have tried multiple solutions without success. Any help is much appreciated.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apk add --no-cache gcc g++ make 
RUN apk add --no-cache build-base python2-dev gpgme-dev libc-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache openssl-dev libffi-dev build-base mariadb-dev libxml2-dev xmlsec-dev xmlsec pkgconf git postgresql-dev

RUN apk update

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir librabbitmq==1.6.1
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir MySQL-python
```

Error:

```
In file included from clib/librabbitmq/amqp_api.c:43:
#10 5.796     /usr/include/assert.h:19:16: error: declaration for parameter '__assert_fail' but no such parameter
#10 5.796        19 | _Noreturn void __assert_fail (const char *, const char *, int, const char *);
#10 5.796           |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
#10 5.796     clib/librabbitmq/amqp_api.c:340: error: expected '{' at end of input
#10 5.796       340 | }
#10 5.796           |
#10 5.796     clib/librabbitmq/amqp_api.c:340:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
#10 5.796       340 | }
#10 5.796           | ^
#10 5.796     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
#10 5.796     ----------------------------------------
#10 5.805 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-X4wzDj/librabbitmq/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-X4wzDj/librabbitmq/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-QtKdGu/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python2.7/librabbitmq Check the logs for full command output.
```

PS: I tried `ubuntu:14.04` base image as well, but that gives `unable to fetch pypi url`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Dockerfile by moving

`RUN apk update`

On top after your image

It worked for me.